# How to get rails response object in code?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, static-pages

I want to manipulate response object from a controller, I just know I can get response like this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :generate_html

  def index

  end 

  def generate_html
    raise response.body # this will show response body content
  end  
 end
```

Now how can I initialize a controller and get its response object?
Because I want to write static_page_generator in a rails application.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to render static pages, the easiest way to do that is just render the page in your controller action.

```
 class HomeController < ApplicationController

   def index
     # renders index.html.haml or index.html.erb 
     # which is in the /views/static folder
     render 'static/index'
   end 

   def home
     # renders home.html.haml or home.html.erb 
     # which is in the /views/static folder
     render 'static/home'
   end

 end
```

Additionally, remember that any page you put into the `/public` folder in the Rails app is static and publicly viewable by accessing the page via http://www.yoursite.com/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I want to execute code to get response, not open a browser to see it.

Comment: Do you mean to generate an HTTP response or to generate JSON/XML?  What are you doing with the "response" that you are trying to generate?